# Object reference not set to an instance of an object error MVC3

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework, actioncontroller

I have a ajax post which give me the values from what the user have typed into my form.

And in my database I have two entites that are being used and I use model first.
However Im getting "Object reference not set to an instance of an object" error when trying to do this:

> goalCardQuestionAnswer.SelectedQuestion.Id = selectedQuestionViewModel.QuestionID;

This is my controller post:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public bool AnswerForm(SelectedQuestionViewModel selectedQuestionViewModel)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
        var goalCardQuestionAnswer = new GoalCardQuestionAnswer();

        goalCardQuestionAnswer.SelectedQuestion.Id = selectedQuestionViewModel.QuestionID;
        goalCardQuestionAnswer.Comment = selectedQuestionViewModel.Comment;
        goalCardQuestionAnswer.Grade = selectedQuestionViewModel.Grade;

        answerNKIRepository.SaveQuestionAnswer(goalCardQuestionAnswer);
        answerNKIRepository.Save();

        }
```

My SelectedQuestionViewModel:

```
   public class SelectedQuestionViewModel
{

    public int? Grade { get; set; }
    public string Comment { get; set; }
    public string SelectedQuestionText { get; set; }
    public int QuestionID { get; set; }

}
```

My database model

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You must initialize your `SelectedQuestion` property:

```
var goalCardQuestionAnswer = new GoalCardQuestionAnswer();
goalCardQuestionAnswer.SelectedQuestion = new SelectedQuestion();
```

Comment: Thanks alot. A small miss, but would never figured it out without help.

Comment: I do not get the "Object reference not set to an instance of an object error" message anymore. Instead, I get "Entities in 'NKImodeledmxContainer.SelectedQuestion' participate in the 'QuestionSelectedQuestion' relationship. 0 related 'Question' were found. 1 'Question' is expected." When I try to save. Any idea why and how to solve that problem?

Answer (score 1):

If I were you I would also add a foreign key property SelectedQuestionId to my model. Then you can set this value and your navigation property will be automatically retrieved upon SaveChanges or when you request the object from your repository.